# Excel - place data on wanted dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

how do I join data with the right dates in continous way?

Example:

I have

```
1/1/2018  (5)
4/1/2018  (7)
6/1/2018  (9)
```

I want:

```
1/1/2018  (5)
2/1/2018  (-)
3/1/2018  (-)
4/1/2018  (7)
5/1/2018  (-)
6/1/2018  (9)
```

Answer (score 0):

First enter the date like eg:
1/1/2018
2/2/2018 
Select this both cells drag the table from the right corner bottom, it automatically enters the date,  or
First enters two dates like eg:
1/1/2018
2/1/2018 and select this both dates and select the column and type "alt EIS" keys simultaneously. Select fill to the required date. That's it

Comment: Once you've done that, use the following formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),"(-)")` to populate the second column (this assumes your first screen cap is for cells on `Sheet2`, in `A2:B4`